# Checkbox is checked once a field has been clicked

Tags: javascript, forms

I have been trying to get a checkbox to be checked once a user clicks on another field however unable to get any further.
Here is the javascript I am using at the moment

```
document.getElementById("Freelance_Sig").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("Freelance_Sig").innerHTML = document.myform.Freelance_signed.checked = true;
}
```

As my form is not html i wonder if thats the issue.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original answer was for interacting with HTML.  You'll need to use something a little different for use with PDF.

Something like this should work:

```
this.getField('Freelance_Sig').onclick = function() { myFunction(); }

function myFunction() {
    this.getField('Freelance_signed').value = 'On';
}
```

There are some good resources on using javascript with PDFs here:

[Basic PDF JavaScripting](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/How_to_enhance_your_PDF_forms_with_JavaScript)

[Getting and setting checkbox values in a PDF](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Turn-checkbox-on-or-off-based-on-value-of-another-field-q60720.aspx)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing this however, my form is not html it is a PDF form would there be just javascript instead of both html and javascript?, thanks

Comment: @Shazan, I updated the answer with a script that should work in a PDF.  There are more resources available at the links too.

Comment: Thank you Adam, this helped alot and the resources are really useful for what I do.